# Mysql get all string matches in single row

Tags: mysql

```
field_id item_id value
-- ----
21  4139 {"repeat-test0":{"main":"test"},"repeat-test1":{"main":"test2"},"repeat-test2":{"main":"test3"}}
21  4140  {"repeat-test0":{"main":"testx"},"repeat-testx1":{"main":"testx2"},"repeat-test2":{"main":"test3"}}
```

I am ultimately trying to get the output to be:

```
field_id item_id value
-- ----
21  4139 test,test2,test3
21  4140 testx,testx2,testx3
```

I need something that will iterate through the different "repeat-testx' to get all of the values.

I have tried substring_index (below) - this can work - but I do not know how many of the repeats may exist in a single row.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    substring_index( substring_index( `vdc_fields_values`.`value`, '"repeat-test0":{"main":"',-( 1 )), '"}', 1 ) AS `id0`,
    substring_index( substring_index( `vdc_fields_values`.`value`, '"repeat-test1":{"main":"',-( 1 )), '"}', 1 ) AS `id1`,
    substring_index( substring_index( `vdc_fields_values`.`value`, '"repeat-test2":{"main":"',-( 1 )), '"}', 1 ) AS `id2`,
    substring_index( substring_index( `vdc_fields_values`.`value`, '"repeat-test3":{"main":"',-( 1 )), '"}', 1 ) AS `id3`
FROM
    `vdc_fields_values` 
WHERE
    (
    `vdc_fields_values`.`field_id` = 21
    AND `vdc_fields_values`.`item_id` =4139 )
```

Output is:

```
id0 id1 id2 id3
-- ---- --- ---
test  test2 test3 {"repeat-test0":{"main":"test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the data normalized. JSONm will be always a bother

## Mysql 5.7 solution

> ```
> CREATE TABLE A (val TEXT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO A Values ('{"repeat-test0":{"main":"test"},"repeat-test1":{"main":"test2"},"repeat-test2":{"main":"test3"}}'),
> ('{"repeat-test0":{"main":"testx"},"repeat-testx1":{"main":"testx2"},"repeat-test2":{"main":"test3"}}')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(val, '$.*.main'),'[',''),'"',''),']','') FROM A
> ```
>
> ```
> | REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(val, '$.*.main'),'[',''),'"',''),']','') |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | test, test2, test3                                                            |
> | testx, test3, testx2                                                          |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6215a366baa8bbfa890b99a492eaf2c4)*

## Mysql 8 Solution

> ```
> CREATE TABLE A (val TEXT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO A Values ('{"repeat-test0":{"main":"test"},"repeat-test1":{"main":"test2"},"repeat-test2":{"main":"test3"}}'),
> ('{"repeat-test0":{"main":"testx"},"repeat-testx1":{"main":"testx2"},"repeat-test2":{"main":"test3"}}')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(val, '$.*.main'),'[\\[\\]"]','') FROM A
> ```
>
> ```
> | REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(val, '$.*.main'),'[\\[\\]"]','') |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------- |
> | test, test2, test3                                           |
> | testx, test3, testx2                                         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a131423130e675b4b07295588fe5be7)*

Comment: Thanks so much for the response - I should have mentioned that I need a solution for MySQL 5.7.

Comment: that is basically the same, only the replacement is somewhat more extensive see the update

Comment: That's amazing!!! Thanks!!!